# ObjC: is an object released IMMEDIATELY when no one references it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I'm having a problem with a view controller that's dismissed and not referenced but still in memory, just wondering in general when is the object actually released in memory when no one references it?

The way I used to test is that I installed the PVC tool from Facebook and use it to print out the view hierarchy when the view controller is presented, after it's dismissed, I make sure no one's referencing it and paused the execution so I can `po` the memory address of the view controller from the previous PVC tool, but I can still see the view controller instance there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be confusing being *released* and being *cleared* from memory.  When the class is destroyed, the memory it occupied is not zeroed, just like when you delete a file in the filesystem, the disk blocks are not zeroed either.

This would simply take up too much time and have very little benefit.

Being released simply means the memory the class occupied can now be re-used.

One way to see if the class has been destroyed is to add a log in the `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"I'm being destroyed");
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant, sorry for the confusion; But do you mean if `dealloc` is called, even in memory the data is no longer there since it's "destroyed"?

Comment: Sorry I just realised, since in ARC you don't need to call release, so the system handles the dealloc for you, so in this case, even if `dealloc` is invoked, the data may still be in memory?

Comment: Yes; the data will still exist intact after the object is destroyed.  It is not zeroed.